# Using variable from previous spec block in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I need to convert input attributes into SOLR request containing three sections, one of them is solrOptions.
in my request I have:

```json
{
  ...
  "firstTranDateRange": "IN LAST 365 DAYS",
  "lastTranDateRange": "In last 60 days",
  ...
}
```

In the output I need to have following:

```json
{
   "searchAttributes": { ... }
   "searchOptions": { ... }
   "solrOptions: {
     "anm_boost" : "1.0",
     "pnm_boost" : "1.0",
     "lastTranDays" : {
       "min" : "00000",
       "max": "00060"
     },
    "firstTranDays" : {
      "min" : "00000",
      "max" : "00365"
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "spec": {
      "searchAttrbutes": {
       // filling up some other attributes not related to the question
      "ltdr": "=substring(@(1,lastTranDateRange),8,3)",
      "ltdr1": "=trim",
      "ftdr": "=substring(@(1,firstTranDateRange),8,3)",
      "ftdr1": "=trim"
      }
    },
    "operation": "modify-default-beta"
  },
  {
    "spec": {
      "solrOptions": {
        "anm_boost": "1.0",
        "pnm_boost": "1.0"
      },
      "searchOptions": {
        "maxRecords": 1,
        ...
      }
    },
    "operation": "default"
  },
  {
    "spec": {
      "lastTranDateRange": {
        "#00000": "solrOptions.lastTranDays.min",
        "@(2,ltdr1)": "solrOptions.lastTranDays.max"
      },
      "firstTranDateRange": {
        "#00000": "solrOptions.firstTranDays.min",
        "@(2,ftdr1)": "solrOptions.firstTranDays.max"
      },
      ...
    },
    "operation": "shift"
  }
]
```

I haven't figured out how to prepend number with proper number of zeros. Help in this will be also appreciated. However, it is not working in the first place. The variables I defined do not appear in the output. In the output I am getting

```json
{
  "solrOptions": {
    "anm_boost": "1.0",
    "pnm_boost": "1.0",
    "wcNameOn": "true",
    "fuzzyNameOn": "true",
    "lastTranDays": {
      "min": "00000"
    },
    "firstTranDays": {
      "min": "00000"
    }
  },
  "searchOptions": {
    "maxRecords": "10",
    "matchIndicators": "TRUE",
     ...
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing incorrectly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with getting rid of `"searchAttributes"` from **modify** transformation presuming the input is exactly

```json
{
  "firstTranDateRange": "IN LAST 365 DAYS",
  "lastTranDateRange": "In last 60 days"
}
```

otherwise keep it, and converting that from ***default*** to ***overwrite*** in order to overwrite all existing attributes. Btw, ***substring*** in Jolt is interestingly different function unlike to their usage in some well-known DBMS products, here *ending index* should be provided as the *last argument*.

Moreover leftPad function will be needed for your case to prepend the values with zeroes.

**`*`** wildcard is used to represent all or rest of the expressions(key names), and **`&1`** to climb one(**1**) level tree up and grab the related key name(**`solrOptions`**)

Thus, you can use the following combination of specs:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=substring(@(1,&),8,11)" // overwrite all attributes at once by using * and & wildcards
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "lastTranDateRange": "=trim", //individual manipulation needed as not having 3 digits
      "*": "=leftPad(@(1,&),5,'0')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "solrOptions": {
        "anm_boost": "1.0",
        "pnm_boost": "1.0"
      },
      "searchOptions": {
        "maxRecords": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      //"searchAttributes": "&",
      "search*": "&",
      "solr*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "@(1,firstTranDateRange)": "&1.firstTranDays.max",
        "@(1,lastTranDateRange)": "&1.lastTranDays.max"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "solrOptions": {
        "firstTranDays": {
          "min": "00000"
        },
        "lastTranDays": {
          "min": "00000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

to yield the ***output*** :

```json
{
  //"searchAttributes": "{....}",
  "solrOptions" : {
    "firstTranDays" : {
      "max" : "00365",
      "min" : "00000"
    },
    "lastTranDays" : {
      "max" : "00060",
      "min" : "00000"
    },
    "pnm_boost" : "1.0",
    "anm_boost" : "1.0"
  },
  "searchOptions" : {
    "maxRecords" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot get rid of search attributes as my input contains many other things, including conversion of miles to kilometers and some others.  I did follow your suggestions in other things, but it is still not working for me. Unfortunately, I cannot expose the whole request here.

Comment: Hi @GaryGreenberg . Please share the whole input in order to be able to evaluate the exact result

Comment: I might loose my job if I post it here. :-(
Can I send it to you in private email?